# Change table column header and table cell element position @media in CSS

Tags: css

I need to make a table responsive using CSS. When the screen size is small I must make the table headers and table cell data appear side by side. How can I do that using only CSS?

```
<table class="hobbies_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th class="hobbies">Hobby1</th>
    <th class="hobbies">Hobby2</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Football</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Snooker</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Reading</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Swimming</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jenna</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Travelling</td>
    <td class="hobbies_values">Singing</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
.hobbies {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}
.hobbies_values {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

#hobbies_table td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: attr(hobbies) }
#hobbies_table td:nth-last-of-type(2):before { content: attr(hobbies) }
```

I know only basic CSS. So this is what I have tried. But I came to know this is the wrong way. So how can I correct the code?
Here in `@media`, I want the `hobbies` and `hobbies_values` to be displayed like this:

```
Hobby1: Football
Hobby2: Snooker

Hobby1: Reading
Hobby2: Swimming

Hobby1: Travelling
Hobby2: Singing
```

Comment: It's preferable to use `grid`, or `flex`. These layouts provide much more flexibility in terms of rows/columns

Comment: Actually the table is already created and rendered in `erb` file. I am new to `css`. So I want an idea on how I can do that.

Comment: Can you provide any CSS you have already tried?

Comment: @SamuelCooper I have uploaded the bare amount of  `CSS` that I have tried.

Comment: @GalAbra, using elements not designed for tabular data for tabular data and going through hoops to make it behave like a `<table>` is just as bad as using `<table>` elements for anything except tabular data (i.e: layout-ing).

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular approaches to your problem:

---

**Solution A** (Bootstrap's classic "table responsiveness")

Simply wrap the table inside a scrollable div and allow it to have its full width. Note this becomes confusing on mobile devices, especially when the user starts scrolling in both directions. A better mobile user experience is often times opening the table in a modal and allowing the user to scroll it in full screen).

---

**Solution B** (Separate markup for each  case)

Have separate markup for each case, hiding the unwanted contents using `@media` queries. The base principle is that you duplicate content and hide the clone you don't want displayed on each responsiveness interval.

---

As with almost anything, no solution is clearly better than the other. It largely varies from case to case.

---

Here's a solution catered for your particular case (based on clarifications in comments):

```css
.mobile_content {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .desktop_content {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile_content {
    display: block;
  }
  .hobbies_values + .hobbies_values {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="hobbies_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th class="hobbies_values">
        <div class="desktop_content">Hobby1</div>
        <div class="mobile_content">Hobbies</div>
      </th>
      <th class="hobbies_values">Hobby2</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Football<div class="mobile_content">Snooker</div></td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Snooker</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Reading<div class="mobile_content">Swimming</div></td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Swimming</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenna</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Travelling<div class="mobile_content">Singing</div></td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Singing</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's actually a separate case of solution B (where, rather than completely replace the table markup - you reuse part of it and only duplicate the part that is displayed under other column's content).

Comment: Actually the layout for all other columns has already been written. I must add the responsiveness only for the hobbies columns. Problem is they are dynamic. There maybe three hobbies columns or four or more. And the present responsive layout is accepted. I must make changes so that only the two columns are visible in the format I described in the question.

Comment: @user,  In that case simply insert the content of second hobby column inside first hobby column and hide it on desktop (and show it on mobile). Obviously, you'll want to hide the second hobby column on mobiles. It is a common technique for grouping columns on mobile devices. To make it clear: the content of second hobby column is duplicated. You show the one in the proper column on desktop and the one in the previous column on mobile.

Comment: Well the requirement is that I should display all hobbies one below the other for each user. I am able to display the `hobbies_values` correctly but I am not able to figure out how to take the text from the `hobbies` header and place the beside the `hobbies_values`. Something similar to this: `#hobbies_table td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: attr(hobbies) }`. I know this code is wrong but I need to place the text side by side instead of before and pass the `content` of a different element.

Comment: @user, I've updated with a snippet for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

May it helps :)

```css
 
      .hobbies_table {
          width: 100%;
      }
      th {
          display: flex;
      }
      
       tr {
          width: 20%;
          display: inline-grid;
      }
```

```html
<table class="hobbies_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th class="hobbies">Hobby1</th>
      <th class="hobbies">Hobby2</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Football</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Snooker</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Reading</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Swimming</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenna</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Travelling</td>
      <td class="hobbies_values">Singing</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful but I want the format only for the hobbies columns where I have specified the class names.

Comment: you want to display hobby only?

Comment: Yes. I need to display only the `hobbies` in the above format.